# How to show components data in another column by using bootstrap and react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to prepare the dashboard kind of website by using React for designing I am using Bootstrap framework. For this I am aligning Navbar vertically to left side by using col-2.
In my vertically align Navbar I have Home component, Course Applications component, Payment Batch component etc.

So what I am trying to do is when I click Course Applications component, then in the URL the routing is working fine. But what ever I put data in Applications component that is displayed in col-2 only But I have to show that data in col-10.

This is my code

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Courseapplications from './Pages/Courseapplications/Courseappllications';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'></Route>
          <Route path='/courseappliations'><Courseapplications></Courseapplications></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid p-0'>
                <div className='row no-gutters'>
                    <div className='col-2'>
                        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                React Dashboard
                            </a>
                            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <Link className="nav-item color">
                                <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
                                Home
                                    <i className="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </Link>
                            <Link className='nav-item commonstyle' to='/courseappliations'>
                                <i className="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                                Course Applications
                            </Link>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-10'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is Courseapplications component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Courseappllications extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Course Applications</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Comment: Please narrow down the question to the actual problem, because there are a lot of irrelevant details(like "in another column..")

Comment: Hi @i.brod  In my code I divided columns into two those are col-2 and col-10. In col-2 column, I aligned Navbar in vertical. Form example In col-2 first Home will come after under Home, Course Applications will come. Now If I click Home component, then what I have written in Home component that I have to show in col-10 column.